# Managing a project on github in different repos or one?

Tags: git, github

An app I am working on (iOS) is being distributed to different businesses and each business needs a few customizations to said app before it is distributed to users on the app store.

Most files will stay the same but quite a few will change based off the businesses needs. **Should the app be built in a way that booleans trigger these changes?**
or **Should we separate the app into separate branches where each branch is for each business?** Problem is with the second solution these branches will never be merged back into master. **Also how would I make changes to the overall app that should affect every businesses app and then merge these back into each businesses app?** BTW these will all start with the same code.

Comment: In-app purchases (for the business-specific features)?  Yes, you'll need a branch for each business type.  Changes to the overall app are done the usual way; you branch, make your changes, and then merge them into the main branch when you're done.

Comment: Too bad you are not doing this in Android Studio you could use Gradle and Jenkins, https://www.jfrog.com/blog/jenkins-new-maven-gradle-release-management-look/ for some ideas but I have no idea if Swift let's you do this. But using git for this sounds like a square peg in a round hole

Comment: What if they later wish to purchase their code?

Comment: They won't ever be able to purchase their code so that isn't a concern.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is to use `git tag` to create a tag for each business, then specify in the build process as a variable (`BUSINESS=FOO`) to change the customisations. You could even try and automate that so it looks for the business name in the tag.

This avoids having to create N number of branches per business, and having to consistently keep them in check with your master branch or having to rebranch every time you release.

Comment: So this would be the use booleans method to trigger changes?